# How can I redirect my contact form to a thank you page

Tags: ee2, forms

Please accept my apologies if i'm not clear, I will try my best.

I have EE v 2.9.2 installed and I am using the built in email contact form.

However, I am trying to get it to re-direct to a thank you page rather than show the ajax message block.

Here is my code:

```
{exp:email:contact_form user_recipients="no" return="http://www.pixelsandcode.co.uk" recipients="pixelsandcode@me.com" charset="utf-8" form_class="form form--full d-showgrid"}

<fieldset class="controls controls--left">
    <label for="name" class="controls__label">What's your name?</label>  
    <input type="hidden" name="message[]" value="--Name--" />
    <input class="controls__control" type="text" id="name" name="message[]" size="40" maxlength="35" value="" placeholder="Benjamin Franklin" />
</fieldset>

<input name="submit" type='submit' value='Submit Form' class="btn btn--primary" />

{/exp:email:contact_form}
```

This is actually a stripped back view, I have other fields but even like this I get no redirect.

Is there something really obvious that I am missing here?

Comment: In your return parameter, you should pass a thank-you page url without base url. Ex:- `return="contact/thank-you"`

Comment: Hi, yeah I tried that.  Maybe something else is going on here that I can't see.

Comment: try `redirect="5" return="contact/thank-you"`

Comment: Right I noticed something in the console log.  It was printing out some css and html which was essentially the standard EE confirmation page.

There was JS for the Ajax which I removed and I saw redirect, but not to the page I wanted it to go to.

Comment: If it comes from ajax, You can redirect on ajax success function on your custom thank you page.

Comment: Right, so I can hardcode it?

Comment: Yup. that's correct

Comment: Ok, that looks like it has fixed it for now.

I think I will be upgrading to EE3, and get something more sophisticated - but for now this works.  So thanks very much, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for redirect and return page, you should follow the doc https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/email/contact_form.html

For now, Response comes in ajax success. You can redirect to your custom thank you page in AJAX success function.